# jquery -change background with animation

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following code for my drop down menu:

```
  <ul>

    <li><a href="#">Menu 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Menu 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Menu 3</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Menu 4</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Menu 5</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Menu 6</a>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#"> Menu 6.1</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Menu 7</a></li>
  </ul>

</div>
```

with the following css:

```
#nav-menu li a
{
    background-image:url('../images/menu_background.png');  
    background-repeat:repeat-x;
    background-position: left top;
    height: 35px;
    line-height: 35px;
    float: left;
    width: 144px;
    display: block;
    color: #f3f6fb;
    font-size: 13px;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-align: center;
}


#nav-menu li a:hover
{
    background-image:url('../images/menu_background_hover.png');  
    background-repeat:repeat-x;
    background-position: left top;
    height: 35px;
    line-height: 35px;
    float: left;
    width: 144px;
    display: block;
    color: #f3f6fb;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-align: center;
}
```

The background image changes when I hover over the drop down menu items. I would like to animate the hover action using jquery or javascript to make the background colour change more smooth/animated.

What's the simplest way of doing it?

Thanks a lot for your suggestion.

Comment: `:hover` - pseudo css cannot be controlled by javascript/jQuery. Is it background color change or image change? If it is transition of images.. the best you going to get is fadeOut and fadeIn.

Comment: Image change because my background consists of repeated images.